# Javascript radio and checkbox length undefined when length=1

Tags: javascript

What this code should do: if you check one or more item, the form does not display alert.

It doesn't work unless there is more than 1 radio and more than 1 checkbox.

When there is only one radio or one checkbox, the console says that `document.formulaire.date.length` or `document.formulaire.creneauferme` is `undefined`.

Can anyone help me?

```js
function check() {
  var msg = "Check:\n\n";

  var datesouhaiteecheck = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < document.formulaire.date.length; i++) {
    if (document.formulaire.date[i].checked) { datesouhaiteecheck++;}
  }
  var creneaufermecheck=0;
  for (i = 0; i < document.formulaire.creneauferme.length; i++) {
    if (document.formulaire.creneauferme[i].checked) { creneaufermecheck++;}
  }
  if (datesouhaiteecheck == 0 && creneaufermecheck == 0) {
    msg += "You have to check one of the items.\n";
  } 

  if (msg == "Check:\n\n") return(true);
  else {
    alert(msg);
    return(false);
  }
}
```

```html
<form name="formulaire" method="post" onSubmit="return check();">
  <input type="radio" name="creneauferme" value="x">Radio<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="datesouhaitee[]" id="date" value="y">Checkbox<br>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't be using `document.*` to access the fields, using `querySelectorAll` and `for ... of` (which isn't necessary in this case since you only need the `.length` - but still can be used to iterate over the collection) is the modern way. Then you can easily get the count of checked fields of a given name inside of a given form.

```js
function check() {
  let msg = "Check:\n\n";

  // First, you find the form. Just querySelector because you only need one.
  const form = document.querySelector('form[name=formulaire]');

  // Then you count all the inputs with a given name inside of the form that are :checked. .length will give you the count.
  const datesouhaiteecheck = form.querySelectorAll('input[name="creneauferme"]:checked').length;
  const creneaufermecheck = form.querySelectorAll('input[name="datesouhaitee[]"]:checked').length;
  
  // Then you perform your other logic, which was good.
  if (datesouhaiteecheck == 0 && creneaufermecheck == 0) {
    msg += "You have to check one of the items.\n";
  } 

  // Although I would avoid comparisons like those. It'd be better to use the original variables used to generate the message above.
  if (msg == "Check:\n\n") return(true);
  else {
    alert(msg);
    return(false);
  }
}
```

```html
<form name="formulaire" method="post" onSubmit="return check();">
  <input type="radio" name="creneauferme" value="x">Radio<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="datesouhaitee[]" id="date" value="y">Checkbox<br>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

`formRef.elementName` only gets expanded into a collection if there are multiple elements of that name, otherwise you get the single element.

`querySelectorAll` will always give you a collection though.

```
document.formulaire.querySelectorAll('[name="datesouhaitee[]"]')
```

Answer (score 0):

if there is more than 1 radio ,it works because  it is not a radio

[image]